# Valgrind to detect memory leaks in java web application

Tags: java, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have web application which runs in Tomcat container. I have been asked to investigate on using Valgrind to detect memory leaks. Is it possible to use Valgrind to profile Java web app? If yes, is it a feasible option over the existing/built-in JVM memory profilers ? I have run the JConsole and VisualVM to see if any memory leaks and found that no such leaks.

As per my investigation so far, I found that Valgrind is suitable for C/C++ applications and Java applications with native code (via JNI).

Though, it is mentioned in Valgrind web site that Valgrind can be used for programs written in any programming language, I couldn't find any examples where Valgrind used for Java programs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think you could use Valgrind for Java. The kind of memory leaks Valgrind detects is just: *You allocated something and forgot to free it.* In Java, there's no `free`, so there's nothing to forget...

There are *other resources* to be reclaimed (file descriptors, direct buffers, etc.), but Valgrind is unaware of them. There are ways to cause a *memory* leak, but they usually involve a classloader, i.e., something Valgrind knows nothing about.

The kind of memory leaks Valgrind detects is IMHO impossible in Java (except for JNI).

Answer (score 1):

valgrind runs for almost all generated code. Coming to java its a bit but does the job. Make sure you use the --smc-check=all option while debugging the memory leak.

Normally to debug a c binary on any target machine,

$ valgrind --tool=memcheck NAME-OF-BINARY-FILE

shows you the statistics of heap summary, leak summary

similarly you would do for java with additional --smc-check=all option.